# Grid.MVC paging IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, grid, iqueryable

I am trying to work with Grid.MVC. And I have a few questions:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(MVC.TableRequest.ActionNames.Index, TestClass.GetAll());
}
```

And my TestClass:

```
public static IQueryable<SheduleProfileModel> GetAll()
{
    var _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    IQueryable<SheduleProfileModel> shedules = _db.Shedules.Include("Profiles").Select(x => new SheduleProfileModel
    {
        DateStart = x.DateStart,
        DateEnd = x.DateEnd,
        Approved = x.IsDirectorApproved
        ,
        UserName = x.Profile.FirstName.ToString() + " " + x.Profile.LastName.ToString(),
        Id = x.Id
    }).OrderBy(x => x.UserName);
    return shedules;
}
```

So, I read a documentation and trying to put IQueryable as my collection. But when I use paging grid.mvc create a query which take all data from database (Not Take().Skip()). The same happens with OrderBy(). How I should sent do DB correct query? And where I should close connection to DB?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to manage the queries for the Grid.Mvc control. You will just fetch all the data using your GetAll method and bind it to the Grid. The logic in the control uses the data and manages the filtering, sorting etc. for you.

You would close the connection in your logic in the normal way just as you would if you were fetching data and closing connection for any other purposes.

To enhance the experience you can also use the Grid.Mvc.Ajax control instead from NuGet which extends the basic Grid.Mvc control. You can find it [HERE](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grid.Mvc.Ajax/).